# Can TikZ draw the cube root function more accurately?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a parabola, two ellipses, and a multiple of a horizontal shift of the cube root function drawn in the following `TikZ` diagram. Only the latter is drawn poorly. Using only `TikZ`, is there a way to draw it more accurately?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}





\begin{document}



\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}



%Part of two ellipses and a parabola are drawn.
\draw (0,0) arc (0:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (0,0) arc (0:-72: 2 and 1);
\path node[anchor=east] at ({-2+sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$E$};
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\draw (3,0) arc (180:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (3,0) arc (180:252: 2 and 1);
\path node[anchor=west] at ({5-sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$F$};
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\draw[domain=-1:4, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-1/9*\x*\x + 1/3*\x});
\path node[anchor=south west, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at (3.75,-5/16){$G$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between (0,0) and its label.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm] (0,0) -- ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75);
\path node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (P) at ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75 ){$P$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between (3,0) and its label Q.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=2mm] (3,0) -- ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=base, baseline={P.base}, inner sep=0] (Q) at ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$) {$Q$};




%
\draw[domain=1.5:4, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {3/2*pow((\x - 3/2),1/3) + 1/4});
\draw[domain=-1:1.5, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {-3/2*pow((3/2 - \x),1/3) + 1/4});
\draw[fill] (3/2,1/4) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north west] at (3/2,1/4){$R$};
\path node[anchor=west] at (4,2.2858){$H$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You couly try using the option `samples` with a reasonably high value, such as `\draw[domain=1.5:4, smooth, variable=\x, samples=200] plot ({\x}, {3/2*pow((\x - 3/2),1/3) + 1/4});`. The higher the number, the more accurate the plot will essentially be, but compilation will also take longer.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht  I knew that `samples` is an option in `pgfplots`, but I did not know it was an option in just `TikZ`. Thanks. What is the default number of sample points?

Comment: According to the manuals, the default value for `samples` is 25. This holds for `/tikz/samples` as well as for `/pgfplots/samples`.

Comment: There might be a gap due to rounding errors at the end of the lower plot. To fix this, you can turn around the values for the domain: `domain=1.5:-1`. You can also simply add  `-- (1.5,0.25)` to the path, which will add the last missing piece to the plot. Or you could try using `samples at` (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663247/47927).

Comment: Remember that pgfmath is a dancing bear.  The amazing thing is not how well it dances, but that it dances at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the curve smoother, you can use the `samples` option that takes as value an integer that represents the number of samples for the plot. Its default value is 25 (which holds true for `/tikz/samples` as well as for `/pgfplots/samples`). The larger the number, the smoother the plot will be, but also the longer compilation will take.

Due to rounding errors, there might be a gap at the end of the plot (near the coordinate `(3/2,1/4)`), which you can solve easily in this case by flipping the values for the `domain` option. This way, Ti*k*Z will start with drawing the plot at the coordinate `(3/2,1/4)` and, thus, in case there is a gap due to rounding errors, it will be at the other end of the plots and not that big a deal.

Another solution to close this gap would be to just add the last missing piece to the path by adding `-- (3/2,1/4)` to it, but doing so might be considered a quick-and-dirty fix. Also, using `samples at` as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663254/47927) could be a solution, but I somehow failed to to apply it here in a satisfactory way. Finally, as suggested in the same answer, using a sample value of 2*ⁿ* + 1 should also prevent such gaps, so you can go with `samples=257`, for example.

The following example shows how to use `samples` and uses flipped values for the `domain` option:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%Part of two ellipses and a parabola are drawn.
\draw (0,0) arc (0:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (0,0) arc (0:-72: 2 and 1);
\path node[anchor=east] at ({-2+sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$E$};
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\draw (3,0) arc (180:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (3,0) arc (180:252: 2 and 1);
\path node[anchor=west] at ({5-sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$F$};
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\draw[domain=-1:4, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-1/9*\x*\x + 1/3*\x});
\path node[anchor=south west, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at (3.75,-5/16){$G$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between (0,0) and its label.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm] (0,0) -- ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75);
\path node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (P) at ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75 ){$P$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between (3,0) and its label Q.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=2mm] (3,0) -- ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=base, baseline={P.base}, inner sep=0] (Q) at ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$) {$Q$};
%
\draw[domain=1.5:4, smooth, variable=\x, samples=200] plot ({\x}, {3/2*pow((\x - 3/2),1/3) + 1/4});
\draw[domain=1.5:-1, smooth, variable=\x, samples=200] plot ({\x}, {-3/2*pow((3/2 - \x),1/3) + 1/4});
\draw[fill] (3/2,1/4) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north west] at (3/2,1/4){$R$};
\node[anchor=west] at (4,2.2858){$H$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble sketching (especially where a graph goes vertical), a good approach is to try to find a parametric form of your graph.  Sometimes that's difficult, but in this case you can invert your expression and plot x as a function of y.  This matches the other answer's graph:

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%Part of two ellipses and a parabola are drawn.
\draw (0,0) arc (0:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (0,0) arc (0:-72: 2 and 1);
\path node[anchor=east] at ({-2+sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$E$};
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\draw (3,0) arc (180:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (3,0) arc (180:252: 2 and 1);
\path node[anchor=west] at ({5-sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$F$};
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\draw[domain=-1:4, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-1/9*\x*\x + 1/3*\x});
\path node[anchor=south west, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at (3.75,-5/16){$G$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between (0,0) and its label.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm] (0,0) -- ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75);
\path node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (P) at ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75 ){$P$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between (3,0) and its label Q.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=2mm] (3,0) -- ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=base, baseline={P.base}, inner sep=0] (Q) at ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$) {$Q$};
%
\draw[domain=-1.78:2.28,variable=\y]plot({((\y-.25)*2/3)^3+1.5},{\y});
%\draw[domain=1.5:4, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {3/2*pow((\x - 3/2),1/3) + 1/4});
%\draw[domain=-1:1.5, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {-3/2*pow((3/2 - \x),1/3) + 1/4});
\draw[fill] (3/2,1/4) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north west] at (3/2,1/4){$R$};
\node[anchor=west] at (4,2.2858){$H$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```