# algebraic curve plot tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to plot this algebraic curve in tikz

[image]

but I don't understand how to deal with these curves in tikz since it's not a function. Desmos tells that it should look something like this

[image]

I only need a curve without axis or whatever and only in tikz.

Comment: Try pgfplots, not tikz.

Comment: Either look it up, or: a) multiply with both roots, b) square it, c) sort terms, d) regroup for either x or y ... and there you go. // OR: introduce a parameter, e.g. a polar plot around (1.5,0). Express x and y by said parameters ... and there you go. // And so on.

Comment: [Q663247](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663247): Somebody has a very similar curve already in *y* (*x*) form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 1]

Considering the equation, an answer to your question should be composed of two steps in my opinion.

1. Find a parametrisation of the curve defined by the equation.
2. Use `plot` of TikZ to draw the curve.

The difficult part is 1) here.  The code below is the explicit development of 2). As for 1), I won't give all the mathematical details.  In case you need them, I could add them later.  I try only to justify the constants and functions appearing in the code.

The equation must be put in a symmetrical form first.  For example changing the `x` coordinate: `s = x -3/2`.  At the end, we come back to the initial `x` coordinate.  So, in what follows I consider the equation

`1/sqrt((x+a)^2 +y^2) + 1/sqrt((x-a)^2 +y^2) = 2/a`

We are looking for the points `P` at distance `r_m` from `(-a, 0)` and `r_p` from `(a, 0)` such that `1/r_m +1/r_p = 2/a`.  It is this geometrical problem that yields the parametrisation.  The parameter is `d`, with `r_m = a/2 +d`.
(The geometrical situation for a fixed value of `d` is represented in the next figure.  The points `(-a, 0)` and `(a, 0)` appear as blue dots.)

[image]

The formulae for `x` and `y` appear in the functions `eForX` and `eForY`.  The domain folows form compatibility conditions.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

\begin{document}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688042/algebraic-curve-plot-tikz

\tikzmath{
  real \a, \dmin, \dmax;
  \a = 3/2;
  \dmin = (-1 +sqrt(5)/2)*\a;
  \dmax = (1 +sqrt(5)/2)*\a;
  \dFixed = .27*\a;
  \rMFixed = \a/2 +\dFixed;
  \rPFixed = \a/2*(\a/(2*\dFixed) +1);
  function eForX(\t) {%
    \s = \t/\a;
    \res = \s*\s +\s -1/(4*\s) -1/(16*\s*\s);
    return \a/4*\res;
  };
  function eForY(\t) {%
    \res = (\a/2 +\t)*(\a/2 +\t) -(eForX(\t) +\a)*(eForX(\t) +\a);
    return sqrt(\res);
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={scale=.5}]
  % translated coordinate system
  \draw[very thin, ->] (-2*\a, 0) -- ++(4*\a, 0) node[right] {$x$};
  \foreach \i in {-1, 0, ..., 4}{%
    \draw (\i -\a, 0) -- ++(0, -2pt) node[below] {\i};
  }
  \draw[very thin, ->] (-\a, -\a) -- ++(0, 2* \a) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[very thin, gray!50, xshift=-\a cm] (-\a, -\a) grid ++(4*\a , 2* \a);
  
  \draw[red, thick, variable=\t, domain=\a/2:\dmax, samples=100]
  plot ({eForX(\t)}, {eForY(\t)});
  \draw[red, thick, variable=\t, domain=\a/2:\dmax, samples=100]
  plot ({-eForX(\t)}, {eForY(\t)});

  \draw[red, thick, variable=\t, domain=\a/2:\dmax, samples=100]
  plot ({eForX(\t)}, {-eForY(\t)});
  \draw[red, thick, variable=\t, domain=\a/2:\dmax, samples=100]
  plot ({-eForX(\t)}, {-eForY(\t)});

  \filldraw[blue] (-\a, 0) circle (1pt) (\a, 0) circle (1pt);
  % \draw[blue] (-\a, 0) circle (\a/2 +\dmin);
  % \draw[blue] (\a, 0) circle (\a/2 +\dmax);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```